# Can we host Bot Connector (not Bot Builder) in our Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, botframework

I understand that Bot Framework has parts: Bot Builder and Bot Connector.
We can host Bot Builder in our Azure subscription.

But is it possible to host the bot connector in our Azure subscription ?

Thanks.
Fabien

Comment: The connector is an integral part of the bot framework, managing the communication between your bot and the various channels. You will not be able to host this yourself.

Comment: So, the hosting of the connector is on Microsoft servers (perhaps their Azure) and all communications go through the USA?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. I thought that might have been your concern, but I can't see any way around it.